# How to use styling from another called component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently using the material-ui react library and have copied the responsive drawer component example.

Is there a possible way to separate the sidebar and header into a separate component and call the sidebar function and my own main content in the main section using the classes.content styling set in the sidebar component

`<main className={classes.content}>
  <Typography noWrap>{'You think water moves fast? You should see ice.'}
  </Typography>
 </main>`

e.g my home function wants to use the side

```
    import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import List from 'material-ui/List';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Hidden from 'material-ui/Hidden';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Menu';
import { mailFolderListItems, otherMailFolderListItems } from './tileData';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 430,
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  appFrame: {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    },
  },
  navIconHide: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  drawerHeader: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: 250,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      position: 'relative',
      height: '100%',
    },
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    width: '100%',
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    height: 'calc(100% - 56px)',
    marginTop: 56,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      height: 'calc(100% - 64px)',
      marginTop: 64,
    },
  },
});

class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    mobileOpen: false,
  };

  handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ mobileOpen: !this.state.mobileOpen });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    const drawer = (
      <div>
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
        <Divider />
        <List>{mailFolderListItems}</List>
        <Divider />
        <List>{otherMailFolderListItems}</List>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.appFrame}>
          <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton
                color="contrast"
                aria-label="open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                className={classes.navIconHide}
              >
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography type="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
                Responsive drawer
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <Hidden mdUp>
            <Drawer
              type="temporary"
              anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
              open={this.state.mobileOpen}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
              onRequestClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
              ModalProps={{
                keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
              }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
          <Hidden mdDown implementation="css">
            <Drawer
              type="permanent"
              open
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
          <main className={classes.content}>
            <Typography noWrap>{'You think water moves fast? You should see ice.'}</Typography>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

Comment: So you want to put the `Drawer` in a separate component but still apply the `content` styling to the `main` element?

Comment: Yes that is correct @jdupont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move separate styling into separate components by just moving the styling into the new React component. I've done your case as an example.

The `main` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

const styles = theme => ({
  content: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    width: '100%',
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    height: 'calc(100% - 56px)',
    marginTop: 56,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      height: 'calc(100% - 64px)',
      marginTop: 64,
    },
  },
});

const Main = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
      <Typography noWrap>You think water moves fast? You should see ice.</Typography>
    </main>
  );
};

Main.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Main);
```

The rest, using the extracted `main` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import List from 'material-ui/List';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Hidden from 'material-ui/Hidden';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Menu';
import { mailFolderListItems, otherMailFolderListItems } from './tileData';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 430,
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  appFrame: {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  appBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    },
  },
  navIconHide: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  drawerHeader: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: 250,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      position: 'relative',
      height: '100%',
    },
  },
});

class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
state = {
  mobileOpen: false,
};

handleDrawerToggle = () => {
  this.setState({ mobileOpen: !this.state.mobileOpen });
};

render() {
  const { classes, theme } = this.props;

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
      <Divider />
      <List>{mailFolderListItems}</List>
      <Divider />
      <List>{otherMailFolderListItems}</List>
    </div>
  );

   return (
     <div className={classes.root}>
       <div className={classes.appFrame}>
         <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
           <Toolbar>
             <IconButton
               color="contrast"
               aria-label="open drawer"
               onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
               className={classes.navIconHide}
             >
               <MenuIcon />
             </IconButton>
             <Typography type="title" color="inherit" noWrap>
               Responsive drawer
             </Typography>
           </Toolbar>
         </AppBar>
         <Hidden mdUp>
           <Drawer
             type="temporary"
             anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
             open={this.state.mobileOpen}
             classes={{
               paper: classes.drawerPaper,
             }}
             onRequestClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
             ModalProps={{
               keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
             }}
           >
             {drawer}
           </Drawer>
         </Hidden>
         <Hidden mdDown implementation="css">
           <Drawer
             type="permanent"
             open
             classes={{
               paper: classes.drawerPaper,
             }}
           >
             {drawer}
           </Drawer>
         </Hidden>
         <Main />
       </div>
     </div>
   );
}
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

So, you can just pull the styling out with the React component that you're extracting. The docs give some more details about [material-ui's styling system](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/).